# Extracting middle 16 bits of a 32 bit long

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

I am reading TCPPPL by Stroustrup. It gives an example of a function that extracts the ***middle*** 16 bits of a 32 bit long like this:

```
unsigned short middle(long a){ return (a>>8)&0xffff;}.
```

My question is: isn't it extracting the ***last*** 16 bits? Tell me how am I wrong.

Comment: We now have four answers saying the same thing.  Please, only answer if you have something useful to add (and even then, consider commenting under the best answer to improve that).

Comment: @MartinBonner Define "best". For someone, that's a short, to-the-point answer. For someone else, it's graphical representation. For yet another one, it's textual description. Let the OP choose by accepting.

Comment: @Angew : I meant "comment under the answer you consider best".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It does indeed extract the middle 16 bits:

```
//    a := 0b xxxx xxxx 1111 1111 1111 1111 xxxx xxxx 
a>>8;   // 0b 0000 0000 xxxx xxxx 1111 1111  1111 1111
&0xffff // 0b 0000 0000 0000 0000 1111 1111  1111 1111
```

Comment: @Ron Sometimes, I value precision over concision; sometime the other way around. Here, I think concision > precision. Won't fix (tm).

Answer (score 3):

`a >> 8` will right-shift the value in `a` by 8 bits. The low 8 bits are forgotten, and bits previously numbered 31–8 now get moved (renumbered) to 23–0. Finally, masking out the higher 16 bits leaves you with bits 15–0, which were originally (before the shift) at positions 23–8. Voila.

Answer (score 1):

a is going to right shift 8-bit (`a>>8`) before bitwise and operation.

Comment: Does this add anything to the answer by bipil? (and the other two answers are better)

Answer (score 0):

Have you noticed the `>>8` part? It shifts the argument right by eight bits, first.